# Leaflet MarkerCluster plugin. Weighted Points

Tags: leaflet, clustering

I have an huge amount of points I'd like to have on the map so instead of sending millions of points across I have grouped together points that are "close enough" to be the same point. So I have moved from 1 000 000 + points down to 10 000s of points which is working well. 
Now however I now no longer have an accurate representation.

So ideally I'd like to a way to modify the child count. I was thinking about overriding the create icon class and looping through all the individual icons getting the weighting for each point and tallying it up. Then at the end have

```
cluster.getChildCount() + total_weighting
```

but that seemed inefficient and was wondering if anyone new a better approach.